# GWT: setting up an asynchronous datagrid with sortable columns and filtering

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I've set up a `DataGrid` with a `ListDataProvider` basically following the [pattern provided in the GWT showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid). My table has a couple sortable columns, and I've implemented a dropdown that filters the values by a particular column value.

I want to change my data provider to be aysnchronous and load one page of results at a time. I've used `AsynchronousDataProvider` according to [this pattern](http://www.mytechtip.com/2010/11/gwt-celltable-example-using_8168.html) on another table in my app and it works well, but in that case I don't have any sortable columns.

My first thought is that `AsynchronousDataProvider` won't help since I don't see how it supports sortable columns (or filtering for that matter). Perhaps I can just modify my use of `ListDataProvider` to only load one page at a time?

Interested to learn how others have implemented this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paging for an AsyncDataProvider is done on the API side (or wherever you are getting your data back from). You can provide sorting parameters and whatnot to this API call.

DataGrid provides range start and length, so you are essentially requesting

```
SELECT * FROM STUFF WHERE ID > start AND ID < start + length SORT BY sortorder ASC/DESC
```

When you create your DataGrid, you can set columns to sortable, and create your own sortOrder. All the data needed for a SQL query is available to create. The sortentry for a table also contains data on whether a column is ascending or descending